# Traits specialization

Tags: c++, type-traits

I would like to define a storage type inside trait specializations. But for certain cases I do not have anything to really define i.e. there is no storage type for certain specializations. Of course using void type is not the way, but I'm looking for something similar. I'm not sure if I'm heading the right direction - one way could be to just use a boolean type since it would take up least space. What would be the right/good way to overcome this. I'm not sure if such a problem has been asked. I did not know what to search for!

```
template<typename T>
struct Traits
{
}     

template<>
struct Traits<TypeA>
{
    typedef std::vector<double> storage;
}     

template<>
struct Traits<TypeB>
{
    typedef std::vector<string> storage;
}

 template<>
struct Traits<TypeC>
{
    //I do not want to specify a storage type here. More like it does not exist. 
    //So what is the correct way to define such a type
    typedef ??void?? storage;
}


int main()
{
    typename Traits<TypeA>::storage myType;
    /*
    do domething
    */
}
```

Comment: What should happen if you try to use `Traits<TypeC>::storage`?

Comment: Nothing you do in the trait class can remove the variable declaration from main. If you actually use storage in another class (e.g. for a member variable) and not within main, you will need to specialize that class. Otherwise, your variable declaration expects a type, so you have provide one (even if it is a dummy type).

Comment: @T.C. As Oguk mentioned I intend to use storage type in a different class.

Comment: @Oguk creating a specialised version of the class just to accommodate the storage type variants seems like a lot of work. Any alternatives?

Comment: It's not to "accomodate" the storage type. You are changing the structure of the class (member variable vs. no member variable). And all the code that will be using the member variable will become invalid and will have to be specialized, too. IMHO, that is a very fundamental change. Even if you don't specialize the user and use some kind of dummy type, the code dealing with the member variable of that type has to stay valid, which is unlikely for non-trivial things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit the `storage` typedef where it doesn't make sense:

```
template<>
struct Traits<TypeC>
{
};
```

Now usage of `Traits<TypeC>::storage` becomes an error, because it doesn't name a type.

Other notes:

- You need semicolons after a `struct` declaration/definition.
- Your `Traits` template (not the specialization) should have no body unless there is one that makes sense for every type.  That is, it should be `template <typename> struct Traits;`.  This will cause usage of it with a template argument that doesn't make sense to cause errors.

Comment: But I don't want an error, I just don't want it to do anything in case of TypeC. Because I intend to declare a variable of "storage type" in a different class.

Comment: @itachi If you don't want it to do anything then you need to take that up with the code that consumes the traits. You can't declare a variable of "no type" so you would need to specialize that code based on whether there is a storage type. You can use SFINAE to accomplish this.

Comment: Exactly (see my comment below the question). You have specialize the user of the trait, not the trait, to do that.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for the observations you made. I missed semi-colons, I'll remember the second suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @itachi [Here is an example](http://ideone.com/TnsPJv) of how you can select different behaviors at compile-time based on whether `Traits<T>::storage` exists.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks! That example helps a lot.